# MapView.Polyline in react native with expo throws an error (I'm testing with an android)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-mapview

I’m trying to draw a line with polyline, but I’m getting this error:

*Error while updating property ‘lineCap’ of a view managed by: AIRMapPolyline
null
Attempt to invoke virtual method ‘void com.google.android.gms.maps.model..u.g(java.util.List) on a null object reference*

This is the code:

```
           <MapView
                style={styles.map}
                initialRegion={{
                    latitude: initialLocation.latitude,
                    longitude: initialLocation.longitude,
                    latitudeDelta: 0.01,
                    longitudeDelta: 0.01
                }}
            >
                <Circle
                    center={currentLocation.coords}
                    radius={30}
                    strokeColor='rgba(158, 158, 255, 1.0)'
                    fillColor='rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3)'
                />
                {drawLine && (
                    <MapView.Polyline
                        coordinates={locations.map(loc => {
                            return {
                                latitude: loc.coords.latitude,
                                longitude: loc.coords.longitude
                            };
                        })}
                        strokeColor='red'
                        strokeWidth={1}
                    />
                )}
            </MapView>
```

The map draws ok, the circle shows ok, but when I try to draw a line, it throws that awful error.

The array of objects is already checked

[image] [image]

https://github.com/rafaelsoteldosilva/maptest

What could it be?

Rafael

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do is to add :

```
lineDashPattern={[1]}
```

as an attribute to your Polyline component like :

```
<Polyline
   style={{}}
   coordinates={route}
   strokeColor={#000}
   strokeWidth={3}
   lineDashPattern={[1]}
/>
```

You should be good to go

Comment: thank for answering. I'll do it and let you know.